# Can't create a database using psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

Am trying to create Database in PostgreSQL using `psql`, for this I have created a `database.sql` file which contains the following script

> database.sql

```
CREATE DATABASE "RStar"  WITH OWNER = postgres  ENCODING = 'UTF8' TABLESPACE = pg_default

LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252' LC_CTYPE = 'English_United States.1252'  

CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

- using the above script I can create the database `RStar` manually(via `pgAdmin`)
- when I try to do the same using `psql`, I get this error:

[image]

and I use the following script to call `database.sql` file using `psql`

```
psql -U postgres  -d postgres -a -f  "D:\PG\Database.sql"
```

Comment: You have some superfluous characters just before `psql`, quite possible [Unicode BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: @MilenA.Radev thanks for the comment i have found the solution for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me

instead of calling created `database.sql` file

```
 psql -U postgres  -d postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE "\"RStar"\"  WITH OWNER = postgres ENCODING = 'UTF8' TABLESPACE = pg_default LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252' LC_CTYPE = 'English_United States.1252' CONNECTION LIMIT = -1"
```

- I should use "escape" character in the database name because the database name is mixed-case - `"\"RStar"\"`

> OS: Windows